# Getting result for mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$usr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pre_name']);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE `name` LIKE '".$usr."'") or die("SQL ERROR"); 
$sqlly = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$adminid = mysql_query("SELECT webadmin from account where name = '$name'");
$adminidresult = mysql_fetch_array($adminid);       

if($sqlly["webadmin"] == 1)
                $status = "<span class=\"pbadge sbc5\">admin</span>";       
        else
        {
            if($usertime > $timedifference)     
                $status="<img width=\"66\" height=\"13\" src=\"img/online.gif\" class=\"mb5\">";
            else 
            {
                $status="";
            }
        }
```

Basically what I want to do is if $sqlly["webadmin"] equals 1 it will display a span with the word admin. The second if represents if the user is logged in it will display an online icon. It would only apply if $sqlly["webadmin"] equals zero. If you neeed more ifnormation I would gladly provide it. Thanks for helping me.

Oh and by the way the issue is that since I'm an admin but it displays the online button but I want it to display the admin span.

Comment: try to debug $sqlly["webadmin"] it seems like it is not getting desire 1

Comment: Do a print_r($sqlly) to check the result and consider using mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: Also check if your query returns one or many rows!

Comment: print_r did nothing for me sadly and I switched mysql_query_array to assoc. Also I tried my query and it should only display one row with either a 0 or a 1. But I'm not sure if its reading the variable correctly  in the query.

Comment: Why are you performing 2 queries against the account table?

Comment: Do: $query="SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE `name` LIKE '".$usr."'"; and take a look at it.

Comment: What do you get when you do `var_dump($sqlly)` before the `if` statement?

Comment: It seems that I get null when I do the var dump.

Comment: Oh and I changed my query to what you gave me and it still didn't work. The second query was put there to show you what I attempted.

Comment: Why are you using `name LIKE`? How many users are you wanting to retrieve.

Comment: can you show us the DESCRIBE account result?